# Access property after inheriting from an abstract class Java

Tags: java, inheritance

I cannot access a field of a class that is a concrete type inheriting from an abstract class.

In Java I create a class of External student that extends Student

```
 */
public class ExternalStudent extends Student  {
String currentSchool;

  public ExternalStudent(String name, Integer age, String studentIdentifier, String currentSchool) {
    super(name, age, studentIdentifier);
    this.currentSchool = currentSchool; 
  }
}
```

where student is

```
public abstract class Student {

    //Attributes
    String studentIdentifier;
    Integer age;
    String name;

    //Associations
    List<Subject> subject =  new ArrayList<Subject>();
    PersonalDetails personaldetails;

    //Methods
    public void setSubject () {
        this.subject.add(new Subject("Name"));
    }

    //Constructors
    public Student(String name, Integer age, String studentIdentifier){
       this.age = age;
       this.name = name;
       this.studentIdentifier = studentIdentifier;
    }
}
```

and external student is set up by my class Application

```
public class ApplicationC {
    //Attributes
    private String personalStatement;
    private String applicationForm;

    //Associations
    Registration registration;
    Student student;
    ApplicationTest applicationtest;

    //Methods
    public void setApplicationResult(String result){
        this.applicationtest = new ApplicationTest(result);
    }

    //Constructor
    public ApplicationC (String personalStatement, String name){
        this.registration = new Registration();
        this.student = new ExternalStudent("Tom",16,"78954","DHS");
    }
}
```

I've set up a simple test class

```
public void testPostCondition() throws ParseException{   
 ApplicationC instance = new ApplicationC("test statement","test name");
    instance.setApplicationResult("pass");    
    assertEquals("pass",instance.applicationtest.result);
         instance.student.age = 16;
     instance.student.studentIdentifier = "78954";
     instance.student.name = "Tom";
     instance.student.currentSchool = "test"; //Error as field does not exist
}
```

But I cannot access the current school of the student instance (who must be an externalStudent). How can I access this field in order to test my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `ApplicationC`, the `student` field is declared with the `Student` class :

```
Student student;
```

Methods available on an objects relies on the declared type, not the object really instantiated.
And `currentSchool` is only declared in the subclass `ExternalStudent`.
So, you cannot access it in this way.

A workaround is  downcasting `Student` to `ExternalStudent` :

```
 ((ExternalStudent)instance.student).studentIdentifier = "78954";
```

And generally, it is better to check the type of the instance before doing it :

```
 if (instance.student instanceof ExternalStudent){
    ((ExternalStudent)instance.student).studentIdentifier = "78954";
 }
```

As a general advice, in Java, you should favor the `private` modifier for fields and if you need to manipulate the base class and access to some fields specific to the subclass, you could define a method in the base class that returns `null` or `Optional` and override it in the subclass with the return of the field.
It avoids cast that may be error prone and that often are symptoms of a conception problem.

Comment: Prefect, yes downcasting makes sense to me. I assume no disadvantage in doing this?

Comment: Thanks, appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Your instance is an AplicationC,
So, "instance.student" is a "Student".
"Student" does not have the "currentSchool" property.
to get to it
* add "currentSchool" property to "Student"
or
* cast your "instance.student" to "ExternalStudent"

note: you will need to handle all the exceptions and over-head of casting etc'

Hope this helps